# Error C2752 on template template parameter with variadic non-type template parameter specializations

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I need some advice.
On VS2017 (MSVC 14.16.27023) and VS2019 (MSVC 14.27.29110) with c++17 the following code fails:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<int A>
struct Bar {};

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
  static void f() { std::cout << "FOO" << std::endl; }
};

template<template<int...> class C, int... Args>
struct Foo<C<Args...>>
{
  static void f() { std::cout << "FOO int spec" << std::endl; }
};

template<template<long...> class C, long... Args>
struct Foo<C<Args...>>
{
  static void f() { std::cout << "FOO long spec" << std::endl; }
};


int main(void)
{
  Foo<Bar<1>> foo;
  foo.f();
}
```

with the following error:

```
'Foo<Bar<1>>': more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
note: could be 'Foo<C<Args...>>'
note: or       'Foo<C<Args...>>'
```

*(the "note"s are pointing to the line `Foo<Bar<1> foo;`)*

As I see it it should be able to determine which specialization to use. Also, on VS2015 (MSVC 14.0.23107.0) it does compiles and works correctly.

The interesting part is that if `Bar` has 2 template parameters it works by matching to the primary template (the first one).

```
template<int A, int B>
struct Bar {};
```

However if the second template parameter has default value it doesn't compile again.

```
template<int A, int B = 1>
struct Bar {};
```

Is there a way to make this work on VS2017/2019, or should I file a bug report on VS forum?

Comment: Your `FOO unsigned spec` message is a bit confusing. The template uses (signed) `long`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, I updated it!

Comment: *Is there a way to make this work on VS2017/2019* ? Well, in my VS-2019 IDE (where I get the error you reported), setting the "Standard" to C++14 resolves the issue. Not sure if that qualifies as an answer, though. :-) ...

Comment: ... I'm trying to find something that changed between C++14 and C++17 that would explain this, but so far I can't. Clang-cl (also in VS-2019) compiles your code without problem, even as C++17. The fact that `int` and `long` are (effectively) the same *may* explain but I would still call it a bug. Changing the second template to use `unsigned` in place of `long` keeps the same error, and that *should* be clearly resolvable (`int` is a better match for `1` than `unsigned`, for sure).

Comment: @AdrianMole It is a useful information that it works with c++14, thanks!
Yeah, it still doesn't work if the other is bool, char, size_t... seemingly all integral types